# flannel pods network installation fails on a vagrant kubernetes master with 6443 port connection refused, even after config copy and owner change

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant

I'm stuck at the well known *6443 port connection refused* when attempting to set a flannel pods network on my *Kubernetes* set of VMs (of `Debian 11` ascendancy), provisioned through *Vagrant*.

I've red many of the questions on SO, and put most of their solutions in application on what I'm showing here, but without success. It means that I'm still lacking something.

Having on my `kmaster` VM this `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.2   bullseye
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1 kmaster kmaster
192.168.56.10   kmaster
```

for `$IP` variable value: `192.168.56.10` gained through an `hostname -I | awk '{print $2}'`,
`$TOKEN` an arbitrary token,
and for hostname: `kmaster`

I ran these steps under *Vagrant* provisioning :

```bash
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=$IP --token="$TOKEN" --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

this `init` command generates an `admin.conf` file on `/etc/kubernetes` having this content:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data:  [...]
    server: https://192.168.56.10:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: [...]
    client-key-data:  [...]
```

then these steps are ran by the provisioning process of *Vagrant*:

```bash
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.kube
cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /home/vagrant/.kube/config
sudo chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.kube/config

# these copies lead to 
# -rw------- 1 root root 5641 Jul 16 04:35 /root/.kube/config
# -rw------- 1 vagrant vagrant 5641 Jul 16 04:35 /home/vagrant/.kube/config

export KUBECONFIG=/home/vagrant/.kube/config

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

systemctl enable kubelet
service kubelet restart
```

I experience the bunch of connection refused known:

```
kmaster: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": Get "https://192.168.56.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.56.10:6443: connect: connection refused
kmaster: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": Get "https://192.168.56.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.56.10:6443: connect: connection refused
kmaster: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": Get "https://192.168.56.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.56.10:6443: connect: connection refused
kmaster: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": Get "https://192.168.56.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.56.10:6443: connect: connection refused
kmaster: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": Get "https://192.168.56.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.56.10:6443: connect: connection refused
kmaster: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": Get "https://192.168.56.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.56.10:6443: connect: connection refused
```

(leaving `export KUBECONFIG` on `/root/.kube/config` doesn't help).

I can see:

```bash
vagrant@kmaster:~$ kubectl get nodes

NAME      STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
kmaster   NotReady   control-plane   81s   v1.24.3
```

for few minutes. But it is doomed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you cat the `kubeconfig` file and check the `server` entry in it, to see if it point to the right endpoint?

Comment: Also, where are you running the `kubectl` command from? Inside kmaster node? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @zer0 I've edited my question to add the config content, and it seems to match the server IP. The `kubectl` commands, including the last one done for checking, are ran through the provisioning steps of _Vagrant_ (meaning: as root user), and the last one (for checking) : connected as a `vagrant` user on `kmaster` VM.

Comment: Have you running the `kubectl apply` _after_ you saw `kubectl get nodes` succeed?

Comment: Simply seems to me that the API server is not running when you are attempting to create the `flannel` overlay.

Comment: @zer0 I'm following an [example provision](https://gitlab.com/xavki/vagrant-k8s/-/blob/master/4-install-master/install_master.sh), that is executed from that [Vagrantfile](https://gitlab.com/xavki/vagrant-k8s/-/blob/master/4-install-master/Vagrantfile). I had to adapt it to make it run on debian 11 (delete  `/etc/containerd/config.toml` and restart containerd), but you are noticing something good... I wonder why _Kubernetes_ isn't started here, and when it should have been started before, to work well. Because the restart at the end assumes it was expected running already. I'm checking...

Comment: @zer0 If I insert `systemctl enable kubelet` and `service kubelet restart` before running the apply command, the `kubelet.service` starts well (I did a checking with a `systemctl is-active` just after) but the `apply` fails with a message:  `kmaster: The connection to the server 192.168.56.10:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` or still with the last messages we saw before.

Comment: We need to debug and ensure running of the API service, not the kubelet. Your `apply` is submitted at the API server endpoint. Can you ensure that before running the apply?

Comment: @zer0 How can I do that? I know only a 192.168.56.10 ip yet, and nothing else. What other service could be registered and isn't, regarding the two involved files ([Vagrantfile](https://gitlab.com/xavki/vagrant-k8s/-/blob/master/4-install-master/Vagrantfile) and [install_master.sh](https://gitlab.com/xavki/vagrant-k8s/-/blob/master/4-install-master/install_master.sh)) I've shown you? Is there another service I shall check with is_active?

Comment: You can check if the `api-server` container is running on the master node by simply doing `docker ps`. You can then run `kubectl get nodes` on the master node, to try and connect with the API server, once you get a valid output. You can try to run `kubectl apply` manually.